# Thymeleaf: th:each for two table rows?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

How can I, inside a `th:each` loop create a group of two rows instead of just one?

I know I can do:

```
<tr th:each="obj: ${listOfObjects}">
   <td>a column with data: ${obj.id}</td>
</tr>
```

However, I want two `<tr>` elements to be created, as I would do with JSTL:

```
<c:forEach items="${listOfObjects}" var="obj">
    <tr>
       <td>${obj.id}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>${obj.name}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Is there a way to achieve that with Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a th:block element for grouping the rows together and repeat them:

```
<th:block th:each="obj: ${listOfObjects}">
    <tr>
       <td th:text="${obj.id}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td th:text="${obj.name}"></td>
    </tr>
</th:block>
```

You can read more about `th:block` [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag)